# Calculating integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2 \frac{f'(x)^2}{f(x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

This is a follow up question for this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828232/evaluating-integral-int-x-0-inftyx2-left-fracfx2fx-fx-ri):

> How can I calculate or simplify the following integral
>   $$\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2 \frac{f'(x)^2}{f(x)}dx$$
>    If I know f(x) is a probability density function?

I have tried using integration by parts, but since the power of $f'(x)$ is 2, it did not yield anything. Any idea how I can simplify it?

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the distribution of which it is the probability density function?

Comment: I believe if there is some additional context for the question it would be helpful.

Comment: This is a general probability density function, if any condition simplifies it, feel free to state and use it.

Comment: This comes from an original problem that you can see it here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828232/evaluating-integral-int-x-0-inftyx2-left-fracfx2fx-fx-ri

Comment: A general form does not exist for this integral.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a general form of your integral in [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828232/evaluating-integral-int-x-0-inftyx2-left-fracfx2fx-fx-ri) or the above question.

$$I_1[f(x)]=\int_0^{\infty}x^2\left(\frac{f'(x)^2}{f(x)}-f''(x)dx \right)$$
$$I_2[f(x)]=\int_0^{\infty}x^2\left(\frac{f'(x)^2}{f(x)}dx \right)$$

Take $$h(x) = e^{-x},\quad g(x) = \frac{2}{\pi(x^2+1)}$$
$$I_1[h(x)]= 0,\quad I_1[g(x)]=-\frac{1}2$$ 
$$I_2[h(x)]= 2,\quad I_2[g(x)]=\frac{3}2$$

Comment: Thanks! But, it looks like I was right about a sign in my calculations which I corrected it right now

Comment: Thanks for giving me your new idea. $f(x)$ should be a probability density function (pdf). $h(x)$ is like a pdf,  but g(x) doesn't look like a pdf. Also, I wanted the evaluation of integral based on same parameters of the pdf, like momnets of that, or limits of x f(x) at zero, infity, ...

Comment: Both of them are valid pdf. You can check that they are integrated to be $1$ and have the same $\lim_{x\to \infty \mbox{ or } 0} x f(x) =0$. :)

Comment: Thanks. That helped me. But, from the beginning, I meant finding the integral in terms of some values of the function. I don't except all to have the same constant answer, but, I think we can find a general answer in terms of some values of the functions or derivatives of them, may be at zero or infinity, or in terms of mean, variance, etc.   For example, $\int_{x=0}^{\infty}x p'(x)dx = \lim_{x \to \infty} x p(x) - lim_{x \to 0} x p(x) $.

Answer (score 1):

You may use iterated integration to solve this too - do you see how?

Comment: No, can you please let me know how?